# RABL API Views Directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rabl

I really like RABL, but it's seeming like it's going to clutter up my views folders with `.rabl` files. I really want to ideally have a seperate `API` views directory so it would be like this:

```
app/
    views/
        customers/
            index.html.erb
            show.html.erb
            ......
        api/
            v1/
                customers/
                    index.json.rabl
                    show.json.rabl
```

What's the best way of achieving this? I'm using this tutorial:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/350-rest-api-versioning

To set up versioning but it doesn't support RABL. I have tried this in `app/controllers/api/v1/customers_controller.rb`:

```
module Api
    module V1
        class CustomersController < ApplicationController
            respond_to :json

            def index
                @customers = Customer.search(params[:page])

                Rabl::Renderer.json(@customers, 'api/v1/customers/index')
            end
        end
    end
end
```

But as expected that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Had the same problem. And solved it by adding this in the RABL initializer

```
# config/initializers/rabl_init.rb
require 'rabl'
Rabl.configure do |config|
    config.view_paths = [Rails.root.join('app', 'views')]
end
```

If you want to ditch this line`Rabl::Renderer.json(@customers, 'api/v1/customers/index')` just change to configuration to be `config.view_paths = [Rails.root.join('app', 'views', 'api', 'v1')]`. In the controller it will automatically link it.

Hope this helps

Comment: How does this handle versioning though?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see this should work. I'm doing pretty much the same thing. What errors are you getting?